# Outputing non-graphic data to pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf

I want to be able to generate quick pdf reports that include data as well as a chart. The chart part is straight forward, but not sure how to export other data.
I have a function that outputs all the required data to the console and plot window in RStudio, but I want to put it all into a pdf.  Is it possible?

Unfortunately, an additional problem I'm having is that reprex can't find my function, so I'm getting this error:

```r
compound_report("aromadendrene")
#> Error in compound_report("aromadendrene"): could not find function "compound_report"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But the actual function works fine to give me the information on screen.
Here's a screen shot of the output:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you considered using RMarkdown and knitr to generate pdf-reports? It can include any kind of plot as well as tables and visible code if you want. But it can be a pain to set up because you need a compatible LaTex installation in order to render it to PDF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.